# Curl request - how to escape unrecognized character in Bash

Tags: bash, shell, curl

I am trying to update a password using `curl`, see example code below:

```
# Define the required variables
keystorePassword="Password123"
userPassword="Password321"
user="username"

# Update the password using curl
response=$(curl -s -u "elastic:${keystorePassword}" \
-XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_xpack/security/user/${user}/_password" \
-d'{"password":"'"${userPassword}"'"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json")
echo "Output: $response"
```

This works OK

But using the below password:

```
userPassword="Password!/\5"
```

Returns the error output: `"json_parse_exception", "reason":"Unrecognized character escape '5'", "status":400`

Is there a way to escape/handle special characters in the `userPassword` variable?

Comment: Don't create JSON by hand. Use the `jq` tool, it will escape it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\` is the escape character. It escapes the character that follows. Since the character that follows is 5, it attempts to escape 5. So, you need to escape `\` in order to use it as a character, so use `\\5`.